# C# Extension methods in F#

Tags: c#, f#, asp.net-core, extension-methods

I am trying to use C# extension methods and fluent APIs from F# but I can’t figure out how to do it. The following snippet is from Asp.Net Core RC2 as an example:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

I can’t figure out how to use APIs like this from F#. If someone has experience working with fluent APIs in F#, maybe they can shine some light on it.

Comment: You can use extension methods in F# exactly the same way you do in C#.

Comment: I have tried to convert the code above but have been unsuccessful, could you show me, maybe that will help

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting? Have you opened all  the necessary namespaces?

Comment: You should have posted your attempt. It would have provided a far better window into your struggles than merely showing the C# code you are attempting to translate.

Comment: I guess that he wants to put each extension method call at new line as me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following translation of the C# 'hello world' example works for me:

```ml
open System
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

type Startup () =
    member this.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder) =
        app.Run(fun context -> context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world!"))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let builder = new WebHostBuilder()
    let host = builder.UseKestrel().UseStartup<Startup>().Build()
    host.Run()
    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the full AspNetCore package.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore
```

You are most likely missing something.